# Change in the US contact's address in US visa application form DS-160

Tags: visas, f1-visas, us-visa

My husband has a US's F-1 visa. He is currently on his [OPT](https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/optional-practical-training-extension-for-stem-students-stem-opt) (optional practical training). I am applying for F-2 visa (F-1 dependent). I have following two questions regarding the form DS-160 (form required for visa application):

1. The form asks for several address (Husband's, US contact point and the place where I am going to stay.). In my case all these are the same that is my husband's current address. However, he plans to change his address sometimes soon (But we don't know exactly when and what will be the new address). Is this okay if his address changes while my visa application is still pending? Do we need to do something for that?
2. The DS-160 form asks for intended length of stay. I want to know how important that field is? As per current status my husband's OPT will end in a few months. However, he is going to apply for extension (Which he will most likely get). So, as per current situation I can stay only for a few months (till his OPT expires) but if gets extension then I can stay for longer (a couple of years). What should I fill in the intended length of stay field? -- A few months or a couple of years.

Please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

---

P.S. This is on behalf of a friend.